# How to configure hue for apache hadoop, apache hbase, apache hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, hbase, hue, webui

I have a cluster of two machines and using apache hbase and apache hadoop. I have to use hue so that I can interect with hbase or hdfs through GUI. I have installed it successfully on my machine(ubuntu 14.04) but it is showing nothing about hdfs or tables etc. and gives error like

1.oozie server is not running

2.could not connect to local:9090

3. HBase thrift server cannot be contacted

How to do setting og hue so that it should connect to my running cluster.

Comment: for oozie setup apache oozie, start hbase thrift server from hbase/bin/start-daemons.sh, and please provide more detals or screenshot of 2nd error

Comment: In addition, why don't you use an open source distribution (like cloudera) instead of install everything by hand ?

Comment: I have a running cluster and also some data about 50 GB or more. So I cannot use other distribution